# Handling Sign Up through api in Devise / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, registration, token

I have created a simple API for a Rails application using token-based-authentication that supports User Log In and Log Out and a couple of other actions to update a User's status. I want this API to be used by devices running iOS. I have based my code on the example found [here](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/). In addition to allowing a device to login and update a User's status I would like new users to be able to Sign Up from the device. However looking at Devise's helper class I can't see any methods that support Sign Up, only Log In and Log Out.

Has anyone managed to implement Sign Up through an API? Are there any security issues with allowing this? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign up from an iOS device is really just a (JSON?) POST to the User resource using a different format responder.

This data is passed in the clear from an iOS device, so make sure you use https on these routes if you're worried about security.

Comment: My problem is that if I hit /users/sign_in from a device I will get redirected as I would if I was hitting it from a browser. I need to get a JSON response. So are you saying I can set up a separate route that responds with JSON? Where and how would I do that?

Comment: sure, just respond to a json format instead of html. Rails 3 sets these up by default usually.

Comment: This answer is marked correct but it does not answer the question specifically for the devise gem. Could you provide more details/code?